# Setting a high number of partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

We are considering an architecture with a Kafka cluster of 3 nodes and a high number of consumers. We see that with a low number of partitions, e.g. 3, and a higher number of consumers, e.g. 16, there will be only 3 consumers actually consuming data, because they are the owners of the existing partitions. To see the owners we do the following:

```
$ bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zookeeper localhost:2181 --group consumer_group

Group           Topic     Pid Offset logSize Lag Owner
consumer_group statistics 0   5335   5373    38  consumer_group_balthasar-1449651803301-63a1d620-0
consumer_group statistics 1   5335   5374    39  consumer_group_balthasar-1449651803820-35a84426-0
consumer_group statistics 2   5335   5374    39  consumer_group_balthasar-1449651803934-2b3cc1bd-0
```

One solution to being able to have many consumers is to increase the amount of partitions to a high number, e.g. 1024. This would put more load on the machines running Kafka, but would this load be crazy? The machines that'll be running Kafka have 64GB RAM and a Xeon E5-2620 CPU (6 cores clocked at 2GHz, 24 hardware threads in total).

Are there any other reasons not to use such a high number of partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the kafka users mailing list someone answered and provided the following article: http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/

It states:

> As a rule of thumb, if you care about latency, it's probably a good idea to limit the number of partitions per broker to 100 x b x r, where b is the number of brokers in a Kafka cluster and r is the replication factor.

We're applying this rule and so far it's going well.